# I am sending email with image. I have only the binary code. Is there any way to send it to email body?

Tags: phpmailer, binary-image

If I use this code it shows me the image. But I want to send this in my email body. But inside the email body when I write this code it shows only the image tag with the binary code.

How can I send this image as my email body image with the binary code?

Is there any way to send this?

I repeat I have only the binary code of Image.

I am sending mail with phpmailer.

```
 <img src="data:image/png; base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAANIAAANBCAYAAAC ..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` URLs should work fine in PHPMailer, but your formatting isn't quite right - there should be no spaces in there, so try this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAANIAAANBCAYAAAC ..." />
```

Failing that, you can attach binary data directly as an attachment using `addStringAttachment`, like this:

```
$mail->addStringAttachment($imagedata, 'image.jpg');
```

PHPMailer will set the encoding and MIME type for you. Note that this expects raw binary data, not base64-encoded.